# Giving postgres access to root files

Tags: permissions, files, postgresql

I created an Ubuntu 14.04.4 server on digital ocean.

I have a directory off the root user called `mapnik/data/`. Inside is a file I want to import to `postgres`. When logged in as `root`

```
ls -l /root/mapnik/data/world_merc.shp
```

yields

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 postgres root 428328 Apr  7 18:17 /root/mapnik/data/world_merc.shp
```

When trying to import to `postgres`, I cannot access the file. If logged in as `postgres`

```
ls -l /root/mapnik/data/world_merc.shp
```

yields

```
ls: cannot access /root/mapnik/data/world_merc.shp: Permission denied
```

Is this an issue with the permission on this folder?

How can I configure this folders permissions so I can import from root to `postgres`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because user `postgres` does have not have necessary permission to read (list) the contents of directory `/root/` (the home directory of user `root`).

Normally the permission of `/root/` is set as `0700` with the owner as `root`, so nobody else except `root` can check the contents and hence traverse further in the directory tree.

So even if you set the owner of `/root/mapnik/data/world_merc.shp` file as user `postgres`, `postgres` won't be able to access the file as the traversal will be blocked because of insufficient permission at `/root/`.

---

Instead of putting the file in `/root/` (and changing permission of `/root/`), choose `postgres`'s home (if there is one) or you home or any place that seems safe and user `postgres` has sufficient permission to do the intended operation.

Comment: Could I change the permissions of the folder so that postgres can import  from /root/mapnik/data ?

Comment: @snowgage Check my edits..you should not change the permission of `/root/`

Comment: Very helpful.. Thanks.. When I log in as postgres could I just store my files right at that users root? e.g. /var/lib/postgresql/data ?

Comment: @snowgage If `/var/lib/postgresql/data` is `postgres` user's home, then Yes, you obviously should !! Check the permissions to be sure..